# How to change color image (jpg,jpeg,png) to black and white or grayscale in node js

Tags: node.js

I used all npm package that support grayscaling but nothing is working properly.
Some of them are working but quality reduced.
there is a good grayscale package named image-grayscale but problem is that when one of the src image (example/image.gpg) file is corrupted then according to promise code stopped to go further.
Below code is the problem.

```
 globby(['./upload/*.*','!./upload/*.ico','!./upload/*.gif', '!./upload/*.txt']).then(function (paths) {
            return Promise.all(paths.map(function (e) {
                    return imageGrayScale(e, {logProgress: 1})                                      }));
                        }).then(function (val) {


   // if one of the file in directory is corrupted then promise is rejected and my code stooped  and i cant do  anything further

 })
```

Please tell  me how to handle error promise to code go further. or is there any solution like callback.

should i go to any other module or can written own algorithim for grayscale please tell me how to convert color of image to black and white

Answer (score 7):

I have used [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) before with success so you could look into that.

An example taken from the documentation

```
Jimp.read("file.png", (err, image) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    image.greyscale().write("image.png");
});
```

Comment: should be an accepted answer - jimp provides a lot of image manipulations and till the date it seems robust compare to other libs

Comment: You sir, deserve an upvote